Замена придаточного предложения деепричастным оборотом
В каком предложении (предложениях) придаточную часть нельзя заменить
деепричастным оборотом?

Мы возвратились домой поздно, так как заблудились в лесу.
Когда луна вышла из-за облаков, она осветила все вокруг.
Рожь, которая золотилась на солнце, была похожа на безбрежное море.
Когда мы перешли через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую
зеленую долину.
Ландыши, которые уже распустились, издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.

Это задание из тестов, в ответах указан только один ответ. Что не верно.
Какие варианты ответа вы выберете и почему?

2-е предложение теряет смысл как отдельная единица информации. Выйдя из-за облаков, она осветила все вокруг.

Как раз второе предложение единственное правильное.

По-моему, стоит повнимательнее присмотреться к пятому предложению.

А что особенного в 5- м предложении?

Второй ответ
Я предполагаю вот что.

Исходные предложения составлены безнадежно криво, поэтому работать с ними не  рекомендуется и не имеет смысла. Придуманные в учебных целях, предложения  часто выглядят неестественно даже в тех случаях, когда их составляют носители языка. Другими словами, по-русски так не говорят.

Особенно нехороши конструкции с придаточными определительными, которые предлагается сделать обстоятельственными.

Особое внимание к предложению 4. Когда мы перешли через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину.


Наш отряд?  Но даже при такой замене неясен переход от мы к нашему отряду. В чем смысл такой замены? И это о стилистике исходного предложения, а как его преобразовать в конструкцию с деепричастным оборотом? Как учащимся проявить свои знания в данной теме?

А это нормальная (с моей точки зрения) запись текста:

Домой мы возвратились поздно, так как заблудились в лесу.
Луна вышла из-за облаков и осветила все вокруг.
Золотившаяся на солнце рожь была похожа на безбрежное море.
Перейдя невысокий горный хребет, мы попали в  зеленую долину.
Уже распустившиеся ландыши издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.
Только в одном предложении использован деепричастный оборот.
Вывод
Составлять такие тесты надо разумно, ориентируясь на правила Розенталя по этой теме, а также на его методику работы с практическими материалами.

Sharon: «А это нормальная (с моей точки зрения) запись текста: Перейдя невысокий горный хребет, мы попали в зеленую долину. ===  Ну конечно нормальная!  Только вот почему эта запись нормальная, а практически аналогичная (где вместо «мы» употреблено слово «отряд») — ненормальная, нормальный русскоговорящий человек вряд ли поймёт. См. Ваше предыдущее высказывание в этой теме: «Перейдя через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину. Стилистика странная: активное и пассивное действие. Вас это не смущает?» И почему же Вас это предложение смутило?..

Я вроде обещала с вами не разговаривать?  Вас это не смущает?  Но вы без меня никак не можете, да?) // Оба предложения нормальные, только вопрос: зачем скакать от мы к отряду? И какое это отношение имеет к проверке знаний по теме?

Эти примеры были позаимствованы из учебника ДЗ Греков Крючков 10-11 класс (Русский язык). Там предлагается такая замена,. Мы возвратились домой поздно, так как заблудились в лесу. Мы возвращались домой поздно, заблудившись в лесу.  Такая замена мне не совсем ясна. В другом месте так написано: Заблудившись в лесу, мы возвратились домой поздно.

А это предложение взято из другого учебника. Рожь, которая золотилась на солнце, была похожа на безбрежное море. ГДЗ, Упр. 288, Русский язык, 10-11 класс, Власенков А.И., Рыбченкова Л.М. Задание звучит так. Замените придаточные предложения причастными или деепричастными. И вот здесь как раз это предложение заменено причастным оборотом. Рожь, золотившаяся на солнце, была похожа на безбрежное море.

Распустившиеся ландыши издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.

Серж, спасибо, я прочитала ваши материалы, тема получилась интересная. Сейчас у меня безнадежно нет времени, а позже я, пожалуй, дам  комментарий в виде ответа. Много нюансов, с которыми должны быть знакомы школьники (по мнению составителей).  И о предложении 4 неясна оценка, оно мне больше всего в заданном тесте не понравилось.

Да, Шарон, полностью с вами согласен.

ОБЩИЙ КОММЕНТАРИЙ К ТЕМЕ
КАК СОСТАВЛЯЛСЯ ТЕСТ (мое мнение)
Нужно было проверить знания основного правила:  действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), относится к подлежащему данного предложения. В качестве исходных предложений выбрали СПП с придаточными времени, причины, а также с определительными придаточными. В четырех предложениях был один субъект действия, а пятое предложение было нестандартным, так как подлежащее там было обозначено разными  словами — мы и отряд.
АНАЛИЗ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЙ
КРАТКАЯ ТЕОРИЯ
Деепричастные обороты  с обстоятельственным значением являются аналогами обстоятельственных придаточных, но что можно сказать относительно определительных? Ведь прямого запрета по грамматике нет, и замена в принципе возможна. С другой стороны, происходит это не часто, что связано со стилистическими ограничениями. Поэтому синонимической конструкцией  для определительного придаточного считается причастный оборот.
А есть ли какие-то правила относительно обстоятельственных придаточных, в данном случае времени и причины? Об этом можно почитать в учебнике по современному синтаксису. Для данной темы интересен вопрос о позиции придаточного предложения относительного главного: фиксированная  она или свободная.
Позиция обстоятельственных придаточных чаще бывает свободной, но при этом при перестановке оттенки значений меняются. Придаточное после главного — это нейтральная позиция, тогда только придаточное зависит от главного; если же позиции поменять, то отношения становятся взаимообусловленными, а это важно для стилистики текста.
Что касается д/о, то там отношения всегда взаимообусловленные, так как оборот входит в состав предложения. Отсюда следует необходимость соответствия по структуре при замене придаточного предложения деепричастным оборотом.
АНАЛИЗ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЙ

Мы возвратились домой поздно, так как заблудились в лесу.

СПП со значением причины (придаточное в постпозиции, нет взаимообусловленности). Замена на д/о (там есть взаимообусловленность) стилистически некорректна.
Сравнить: Так как мы заблудились в лесу, то возвратились домой поздно. Придаточное в препозиции, взаимообусловленные отношения. Замена возможна: Заблудившись в лесу, мы возвратились домой поздно.
Порядок предложений зависит от контекста, оба варианта возможны, например:
(1) Вчера ездили в заповедник. Так как заблудились в лесу (= заблудившись в лесу), вернулись поздно. (2) Вчера поздно вернулись, так как заблудились в лесу.
Вывод. Надо было составить СПП с придаточным в препозиции, тогда замена возможна.

Когда луна вышла из-за облаков, она осветила все вокруг.

Придаточное в препозиции, отношения взаимообусловленные, замена возможна: Выйдя из-за облаков, луна осветила все вокруг.

Рожь, которая золотилась на солнце, была похожа на безбрежное море. Корректна замена на причастный оборот, который имеет определительное значение и является синонимической конструкцией Рожь, золотившаяся на солнце, была похожа на безбрежное море.

Замена д/о возможна с точки зрения грамматики: Золотясь на солнце, рожь была похожа на безбрежное море.
Но есть проблемы со стилистикой: активное действие в придаточном и пассивное состояние в главном.  Этот вариант будет иметь метафорическое значение, характерное для художественных описаний, поэтому для учебных заданий не подходит.

Ландыши, которые уже распустились, издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.

Ситуация аналогичная (корректна замена на причастный оборот):  Уже распустившиеся ландыши издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.
В то же время замена д/о возможна по грамматике: Уже распустившись, ландыши, издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.
Но это не просто информационное сообщение, а художественное (развернутое) описание цветущих ландышей. Поэтому для учебных заданий не рекомендуется.

Когда мы перешли через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину.

Некорректна стилистика исходного предложения (непонятно использование двух обозначений (мы и отряд) для одного субъекта действия). При этом по грамматике замена д/о возможна в двух вариантах:
(1) Перейдя через невысокий горный хребет, мы попали в ласковую зеленую долину. (2) Перейдя через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину.
Но по стилю следует выбрать первый вариант (активное действие субъекта).  Второй вариант возможен, к примеру, в таком предложении: Отряд попал в засаду.
ВЫВОД. Корректно только предложение 2 из всего теста, остальной материал требует доработки.

https://ask.fm/russian/answers/173784179772

Серж, у меня нет доступа к этому ресурсу. Скажите коротко, если у меня что не так, исправлю тогда.  Обсудим заодно.  Хотелось бы частные суждения как-то привязать к грамматике СПП, а к конкретному анализу добавить общую методику.

См. дополнение.

Они полностью солидарны с вами.

✦ Я предполагаю, что в тестах указано предложение № 4, так как замена на деепричастный оборот здесь невозможна (в главном и придаточном предложении разные подлежащие, то есть производители действий).
• Предложение № 2 чаще всего выглядит так:
Когда луна вышла из облаков, она осветила бледным светом окрестность.
Тут один производитель действия — луна (просто во избежание повтора вместо существительного использовано местоимение):
Когда луна вышла из-за облаков, она [луна] осветила все вокруг.
С деепричастным оборотом:
Выйдя из-за облаков, луна осветила все вокруг.
• Возможен, конечно, и другой вариант:
Луна вышла из-за облаков, осветив все вокруг.
Но он не является верным для этого теста, так как на деепричастный оборот заменено главное предложение.
• "Выход" луны из-за облаков с освещением чего-либо имеется в примерах:
Белая луна со слизанным боком вышла из-за облака и теперь блёкло освещала широкую кривую дорогу (В. Тихонов. Наследство одержимого).
Луна уже вышла из-за облаков и теперь ровно освещала всё вокруг призрачным жёлто-голубым светом (А. Чугункин. 2024).

«Я предполагаю, что в тестах указано предложение № 4, так как замена на деепричастный оборот здесь невозможна…» === Но ведь можно предложить такую замену: Перейдя через невысокий горный хребет, наш отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину. Правда, если «мы» и «отряд» не одно и то же, то такая замена не пройдёт.

Ну не знаю... Мы перешли, отряд попал... Местоимения наш в предложении нет. Искусственное оно, это предложение, подогнанное для теста. Оригинальное, предполагаю, выглядит так: Перейдя через невысокий хребет, мы попали в соседнюю долину, поросшую густым лесом (В. К. Арсеньев. По Уссурийскому краю).

@Слава, в ответах теста все запутано.

А что, другие предложения можно заменить?

Все проще, давайте по тупому рассуждать, ну прям совсем примитивно.
2. Когда луна вышла из-за облаков, она осветила все вокруг.
4. Когда мы перешли через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину.

Заменяем придаточную и смотрим на сохранение смысла и грамматики:
2. Выйдя из-за облаков, она осветила все вокруг.
4. Перейдя через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину.

Теперь очевидно, что 4 корректное предложение, сохраняющее смысл, а 2 бессмыслица.
PS
Но я согласен что в 4 заменять не совсем корректно, там мы и наш отряд это грамматически разные субъекты, пусть даже по смыслу они одинаковы, ведь указательное местоимение идет до субъекта на который оно якобы ссылается, а это противоречит ссылке и делает его полноправным другим субъектом (грамматически).

Ничего не понимаю, честное слово... Из ответа: 1. Теперь очевидно, что 4 корректное предложение, сохраняющее смысл... 2. PS Но я согласен что в 4 заменять не совсем корректно... // "Дык" где же ж ваше правильное решение? P. S. По поводу бессмыслицы: я в своем ответе привела похожие примеры (про луну и свет). Не спорю, сейчас, к сожалению, литература — отдельно, а тестирование — совсем отдельно. Не нужно думать — "ответ надо найти быстро"! P. P. S. И — добавьте, пожалуйста, в свой ответ необходимые знаки препинания.

Если не понимаете, то PS не читайте, считайте что его вообще не существует. Без него все понятно?

Что касается запятых, всегда их рассыпал как попало. Раньше, от непонимания, а теперь принципиально. Не вижу в них смысла, ведь если грамматическая структура однозначна, то зачем её подчеркивать чего-то выделять по каким-то правилам, это наоборот усложняет. Помимо грамматики надо еще держать в голове правила пунктуации (а это чистые условности в отличие от грамматики), чтобы одно накладывать на другое. Конечно есть и другие функции у запятых, типа как в "казнить,нельзя" или выразительная функция (тупо паузы). но это редкость. В основном же тупо дублировать грам структуру по условным "правилам"

Изумительная откровенность по поводу запятых.  И это при том, что большинство задач на форуме именно о запятых. Мы занимаемся ерундой?)  Вы не понимаете, что запятые могут изменить грамматику и семантику? //  Перейдя через невысокий горный хребет, отряд попал в ласковую зеленую долину.   Стилистика странная: активное и пассивное действие.  Вас это не смущает?

"Мы занимаемся ерундой?)" Ну конечно). "Активное и пассивное действия" - оба действия активны: перейдя отряд попал

@user190920
О ЗАПЯТЫХ для вас (статья по материалу форума) https://proza.ru/2024/04/26/1303

Вот что написал ChatGPT. На сайте "Современный русский" лингвисты также согласились с моими доводами. Интересно было бы прочитать ответ Грамот.ру, но они пока не ответили.
Деепричастный оборот обозначает добавочное действие, которое выполняет то же лицо, что и в главной части предложения. Деепричастие должно соответствовать главному действию по смыслу и времени, а также субъекту, совершающему действие.
Рассмотрим каждое предложение по отдельности.
Мы возвратились домой поздно, так как заблудились в лесу.
Формально предложение "Заблудившись, мы вернулись домой поздно" возможно с точки зрения грамматики. Однако при такой формулировке основной акцент смещается с причины (почему именно мы вернулись поздно) на добавочное действие. В оригинальном предложении "Мы  возвратились домой поздно, так как заблудились в лесу" подчеркивается причинно-следственная связь: мы вернулись поздно именно из-за того, что заблудились.
Если заменить на деепричастие "заблудившись", фраза станет менее ясной в смысле причинности, и логика немного изменится: создается впечатление, что заблудились, а затем просто вернулись, но не обязательно "мы вернулись поздно именно из-за этого.
Поэтому грамматически это возможно, но стилистически такая замена не будет полностью эквивалентной по смыслу.
Предложение "Золотясь, рожь была похожа на безбрежное море" не совсем удачна. Деепричастие "золотясь" предполагает активное действие, которое выполняет субъект предложения, то есть рожь. Но рожь — это неодушевленный объект, который сам по себе не может выполнять действия. Здесь "золотиться" скорее описывает её состояние, а не активное, добавочное действие.
Луна, выйдя из-за облаков, осветила все вокруг. Здесь всё верно. Луна — активный субъект и поэтому предложено верно.
Что касается тех предложений, которые привела Рима Михайлова.
В художественной литературе, действительно, встречаются примеры, где такие конструкции с деепричастиями, как "золотясь", используются для описания состояний или явлений природы. Писатели, такие как Паустовский, Грин или Искандер,  используют подобные обороты, создавая поэтические и метафорические образы. Это позволяет оживлять неодушевленные предметы, приписывая им действия, характерные для одушевленных существ.
Но в формальном или строгом грамматическом контексте, особенно в учебных примерах, такой оборот может быть признан неудачным из-за грамматического несоответствия: неодушевленные предметы, как правило, не могут выполнять активные действия.
Так что в литературе такие предложения допустимы, но в нейтральной речи или учебных примерах они могут показаться стилистически некорректными.
Дополнение от 21.10.2024.

Дополнение от 1.11. 2024.
Ответ Грамоты.ру.
В предложении 4, бесспорно, допущена ошибка, так как действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом) должно относиться к подлежащему данного предложения. Ср. деепричастный оборот в других предложениях:

Заблудившись в лесу, мы возвратились домой поздно. (Деепричастный оборот обычно предшествует сказуемому, если обозначает причину другого действия.)

Выйдя из-за облаков, луна осветила все вокруг. Деепричастный оборот обычно предшествует сказуемому, если обозначает предшествующее действие.


В предложениях 3) и 5) приаточные предложения следует заменить не деепричастным, а причастным оборотом:

Рожь, золотящаяся на солнце, была похожа на безбрежное море.

Уже распустившиеся ландыши издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны



Серж: «Вот что написал ChatGPT…» === А по поводу 4-го и 5-го предложений этот чат ничего не написал?

@Слава Я ничего не спрашивал об этих предложениях. Кстати, читайте комментарий Шарону по поводу этих предложений. –

На этом сайте 2-е предложение совершенно другое, там про какую-то кожуру. Что касается доводов, то рассуждения любопытные и наверняка по своему логичны, но к практическому реальному языку не имеют отношения, хотя бы потому, что все 4-5 предложений проглатываются не поморщившись.

@user190920, см. примеры Риммы Михайловой.

Что касается предложений, все уже сказано. В тестах ошибка.

В тестах 5 предложений и все кроме одного ошибка ? Лингвисты только на одно-единственное предложение взъелись (про лес), да и то сами же сказали "весьма условно", "сначала согласились, потом нет", итп. А по-другому говоря, все ок с тем предложением.

А про рожь это вообще смех. Таких предложений миллион в РЯ. Машина серебрясь на солнце, стояла... Крыша блестя на солнце, отражала. Странно что чат GPT посчитал это неудачным, тогда надо весь РЯ считать неудачным.

В ваших предложениях есть обстоятельственное значение. В предложении по рожь состояние.

Это тест, поэтому ответ надо найти быстро.
Понятное дело, что используется главное правило для деепричастного оборота: Действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), относится, как правило, к подлежащему данного предложения.
Предложение 4 вычисляется сразу по этому принципу, даже обороты составлять необязательно.
Мы возвратились домой поздно, так как (мы) заблудились в лесу.
Когда луна вышла из-за облаков, она осветила все вокруг.
Рожь, которая (она) золотилась на солнце, была похожа на безбрежное море.
Когда МЫ перешли через невысокий горный хребет, ОТРЯД попал в ласковую зеленую долину.
Ландыши, которые (они) уже распустились, издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
 Вы хотите сказать, что все предложения можно 
 заменить д/о? 

Так что же говорить, надо просто заменить) Но стилистика вне критики, ведь такая задача и не ставилась)  И я вообще не понимаю, почему в теме так много разговоров) Тест решается просто, быстро и однозначно.
Заблудившись в лесу, мы возвратились домой поздно.
Выйдя из-за облаков, луна осветила все вокруг.
Золотясь, рожь была похожа на безбрежное море.
Уже распустившись, ландыши издавали тонкий, нежный аромат весны.

Вы хотите сказать, что все предложения можно заменить д/о?

Все, кроме 4. А вы сомневаетесь? Какое нельзя?

Золотиться — какой глагол?

@Серж Золотиться (http://www.ckii.ru/Library/SearchInVocabulary?Filter.SearchText=%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&Filter.SearchType=DefinitionsForWord&Filter.VocabularyId=20) В ссылке: Пыль, золотясь от вечерней зари, оседала на деревьях (Паустовский. Разливы рек). Из Нацкорпуса: Куски кожуры, как капли солнца, медленно тонули, все тусклее и тусклее золотясь сквозь живую толщу воды (Фазиль Искандер); Тогда, расцвечиваясь и золотясь, вышел из саженного кокона, огромный свиток шелка, шириной футов пятнадцать и длиной почти во весь зал (А. С. Грин).

@Серж  Золотиться – глагол НСВ, и деепричастие золотясь обозначает длящееся действие, протекающее в момент времени в прошлом, заданный формой сказуемого "была похожа".  Поэтому грамматика предложения с д/о будет корректной.

активное действие в придаточном и пассивное состояние в главном

Полно таких предложений в русском
Смеясь, он казался куда добрее и проще
Золотясь, рожь казалась похожей на море


Такие предложения могут быть, но они не отвечают литературной норме.
